# Unique external IP in virtualbox?

Tags: networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine

Using Windows 7 in Oracle VirtualBox I see that my external IP of the VM is the same as my PC. Can I make it that my VM has a different external IP?

Comment: You can't.  I assume your ISP has only assigned you a single ip address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a VPN client in your VM to get a different public IP, but outside of that unless you have a block of IP addresses from your ISP, that won't be possible.